# Writing to a MySQL database with Ember and Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ember.js

I’m new working with Ember.js and I’m confused about a few things. My real issue is working with MySQL and ember-data. I’ve worked through a few tutorials and found this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljLxZw-XStw) very useful. At this point, I can create an app that runs on top of a Node.js server. The node server communicates with a mysql database and creates a RESTful API that the ember app consumes. I have no problem getting data from the mysql database and displaying it. But I cannot figure out how to save or update data in the MySQL database. I vaguely understand the concept of the ‘store’ and can push objects into it and display them, but that's it. Are there any examples out there of how to write or update a mysql database using ember-data and Node.js?

EDIT: this question is really asking about the structure of an ember-mysql app and what has worked in production for others.

This is an example of pushing into the store in the routes/message.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("done waiting...")

            self.store.push({
                data: [{
                    id: 11,
                    type: 'message',
                    attributes: {
                        message: 'New Message'
                    },
                    relationships: {}
                }]
            });
        },1000);
        return self.store.findAll('message');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

From ember-data perspective it doesn't matter if you use mysql or any other database engine. Ember-data only communicates with an API - a RESTful [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) by default.

So the node.js part of your application should implement endpoints for both reading and saving data. However writing this API from scratch is a waste, it'd be much easier if you used a framework - if you wish to stick with node.js check out [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/), if not, give [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) a try.

In both of those frameworks it's pretty straightforward to generate a working RESTful API that ember-data could consume.

As for your code example: `Store` is a layer in ember-data that's responsible for managing record's data in browser memory. `Push`ing to `Store` only adds record to memory (technically records are `push`ed to `Store` when you read them from the API).

In order to save a model, just call `model.save()` which sends a `POST` (when creating) or a `PUT` (when updating) request to the API - at least with default JSON API `Adapter`. (`Adapter` is the layer that understands how your API works and communicates with it.)

If you're just building a prototype, give [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) a try - that's basically a ready backend for your JavaScrip app. You could than ditch the node.js part at all - at least for the time beeing.